# Is there a way to select tables based on labels in a Bigquery Query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Tables in BigQuery can be assigned [labels](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-managing-labels#creating_or_updating_a_table_or_view_label).

I have tables in BigQuery which can have one or more labels. I have looked into the [querying multiple tables using wildcard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables). However, in my case the labels can change dynamically and each table can have more than 1 label.

One way that I could go about this is to have another metadata table which has the details of all the tables and its labels. I could run a query on this first to get all the required tables and then run the actual query for these tables. But I wanted to avoid this since it is a hassle to maintain this metadata table (when the label changes, table is deleted etc.). Also, I might hit the limit on maximum unresolved query length (256KB) with this approach.

So I wanted to know if there is a way to select tables based on the labels, for querying, similar to `_TABLE_SUFFIX`? Something like below?

`select * from [x.y] where x has labels [a,b] and y has labels [c,d]`

Of course, all the tables which match the labels should have same schema and properties (partitioning etc.) for the query to succeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying tables by labels is not possible. You can see supported standard SQL operations if you look in standard SQL [query syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax) and [functions & operators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators).

Labels are used to help you organize Google Cloud Platform resources in this case BigQuery resources.

Answer (score 2):

This feature has been added since the original answer was accepted. Use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS` view documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/viewing-labels#sql). An example below is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71148497):

```sql
select
   table_name,
   vals.*
from sample_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS
cross join unnest(array(
    select as struct arr[offset(0)] key, arr[offset(1)] value
    from unnest(regexp_extract_all(option_value, r'STRUCT\(("[^"]+", "[^"]+")\)')) kv, 
    unnest([struct(split(replace(kv, '"', ''), ', ') as arr)])
  )) vals
where
  option_name = 'labels'
  and vals.key = 'my-label-name'
  and vals.value = 'my-label-value'
```