# How can I unnest a string of an array of structs in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The bigquery method: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS returns a string of arrays of structs for option_value when option_name is "labels". More information is here: [TABLE_OPTIONS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#table_options_view) For example, I create the table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE sample_dataset.sample_table
OPTIONS(
    labels=[("env","dev"),("dep","hr")]
)
```

I then query from the table:

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS
```

This returns the following:

```
[
  {
    "table_catalog": "sample_project",
    "table_schema": "sample_dataset",
    "table_name": "sample_data",
    "option_name": "labels",
    "option_type": "ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, STRING>>",
    "option_value": "[STRUCT(\"env\", \"dev\"), STRUCT(\"dept\", \"hr\")]"
  }
]
```

How can I transform this table to something more like:

```
[
  {
    "table_catalog": "sample_project",
    "table_schema": "sample_dataset",
    "table_name": "sample_data",
    "env": "dev",
    "dept":"hr"

  }
]
```

I have tried all the answers to this stack overflow question with no luck:
[Stringified array bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199823/how-to-convert-stringified-array-into-array-in-bigquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, 
  array(
    select as struct arr[offset(0)] key, arr[offset(1)] value
    from unnest(regexp_extract_all(option_value, r'STRUCT\(("[^"]+", "[^"]+")\)')) kv, 
    unnest([struct(split(replace(kv, '"', ''), ', ') as arr)]) 
  ) options 
from sample_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS
where table_name = 'sample_data'
and option_name = 'labels'
```

if applied to sample use case in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option to the nice solution offered by @Mikhail_Berlyant would be to use the `TO_JSON` function when it will be available.

Since January 2022, `JSON` is now a data type supported by BigQuery, but is not yet Generally Available.

When it becomes GA (or if you are lucky enough to already have access, I think it's possible to apply) you can simply do:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT (option_value),
    TO_JSON(option_value) AS option_value_json
FROM sample_table.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS
```

And you will be able to extract the information you need very simply with the BQ JSON function.

Some refs: [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions)

Comment: This doesn't work since the value is stored literally as "[STRUCT(\"env\", \"dev\"), STRUCT(\"dept\", \"hr\")]", which is not valid JSON. Wonder why google would use such an atrocious format.